# discord.py: How can i limit to only one reaction on a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi i want to know if it's possible to setup so a message lets say has 5 reactions added.
"A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
And a user first react with "A", and then react with "B", then i want the bot to remove the newest reaction in this case reaction "B".

So the goal is to have the user first remove his first reaction before he can react to a new.
Tried this so far:

```
for r in message.reactions:
    if payload.member in await r.users().flatten() and not payload.member.bot and str(r) != str(payload.emoji):
      await message.remove_reaction(r.emoji, payload.member)
```

But that just remove the old selected emoji.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Carlos i added it up in the question!